# How to remove the skip after a listing when "\parskip" is increased with "\baselineskip"?

Tags: spacing, listings, paragraphs, parskip

I've increased `\parskip` with `\baselineskip` to use the "skipped" paragrahs style instead of the default "indented" style. However, this causes all listings to automatically include a baselineskip afterwards (see below).

[image]

How do I remove it? A minimal example is included below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\lstset{%
  frame=single,
}

\begin{document}
bla bala bla
\begin{lstlisting}
test test test
\end{lstlisting}
bla bal bal
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`parskip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package to deal with this. The basic problem is that `parskip` gets used all over the place. The `parskip` package tries to have the change of paragraph skip length only have an effect where you actually intend it to. Simply add `\usepackage{parskip}` to your preamble above the command that changes the length.

Comment: Although I did "solve" the problem by reverting to using the indented style of paragraphs, I'll set this answer as accepted.

Comment: This approach instead put additional space.